# Can a wizard or witch lose his magic?

Tags: harry-potter, magical-theory

With my understanding and from an absolute knowledge of the subject, that according to JK Rowling, wizards and witches are born with their magic and it's a part of their DNA. Magical people are genetically somewhat different from Muggles, and this difference is the reason for their magical abilities. (Extracted from posts of this page)

The answers for these questions  are related, but none suitably answer whether a wizard can permanently lose their powers: [post 1](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/53487/in-harry-potter-what-is-the-ultimate-source-of-magicians-and-magic/53489#53489), [post 2](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/141568/if-an-animagus-witch-or-wizard-loses-their-magic-through-emotional-stress-will-t) and [post 3](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/157674/can-genetics-explain-the-various-magical-abilities).

And other information source:

[Magic Genes](http://harrypotter.wikia.com/wiki/Magic_genes)

Can a wizard lose his magic and become a squib or somthing like this? If this is possible, can you explain how it would work?

**EDIT 1: Why [this question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/60227/is-it-possible-to-lose-or-gain-magic-blood/60229#60229) doesn't answer my question**

- All of the examples of the answer are affected or produced by emotional trauma or psychological state, and would presumably be reversible if the wizard gets to a better mental state. *However I'm looking for a way to entirely "delete" a wizard's ability to use magic or otherwise render their magical powers unusable.*
- In the examples given in the answers, the characters never lose their magical ability to the point where it would be impossible for them to regain their powers. They are only in a temporary state where they are unable to use their magic - they don't permanently lose their powers. *I'm asking about a situation where this is actually a permanent state, or if there's a way to make the temporary state permanent.*
- The answer may possibly be outdated in some things, for example the Ariana Dumbledore case. In "Fantastic Beasts and Where to Find Them" the existence of the Obscurus gives an explanation for what happens in these cases... It's not confirmed yet as canonical to say this is what happened to Ariana, but her symptoms as described are very similar to those of one of the characters in "Fantastic Beasts and Where to Find Them".

Comment: The question didn't "solve your problem" because __it can't be sold__. You can't take away magical ability __without killing the mage__. Period.

Comment: @Gallifreyan For this is the question no? for answer it with not or yes. I don't know if exist some possibility for take away the magician ability, if i know the answer i don't  do the question.

Comment: You're expecting someone to prove a negative, which is by definition impossible. The answer there lists all known examples of a witch/wizard "losing" their magic, while noting that they didn't really "lose" their magic, only lost control of it. Your last bullet point is somewhat moot - that answer obviously draws from the books, including the last book, so there's no need to include films. You can ask for relevant supporting quotes in comments.

Comment: Note: many have found that, if they've lost their magical abilities, they should see if they just fell behind the couch.